# UseParams is refreshing but UseEffect is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I am using `react-router-dom : 6.4.2` and `react : 18.02.0`

For a Detail page I am using useParams() to get the id from the url to open the current user page.

When I switch to the next user page using

```
<Link to={`/users/${Number(id) + 1}`}>Next User</Link>
```

, the id I get from useparams changes, but useEffect doesn't work again, even though I hooked the id to useEffect.

**I check the id with console.log(id) and it changes.** Why is useEffect not working? Where am i doing wrong?

## Users.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
//import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


function Users() {

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => setUsers(data))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));

    }, [])


    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Users</h2>
            {
                loading && <div >Yükleniyor..</div>
            }
            <ul className="user-list">
                {
                    users.map((user) => (
                        <li key={user.id} >
                            <Link to={`${user.id}`} state={user}>{user.name}</Link>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Users
```

## UserDetail.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link, useParams, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function UserDetail() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const location = useLocation();
    const [user, setUser] = useState(location.state);
    console.log(location)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!user?.id) {
            fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => setUser(data))
            console.log("if olan")
        }

    }, [id, user])


    return (
        <div>
            <h2>
                User Detail
            </h2>

            {user && <pre>
                {JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}
            </pre>}
            {/* {location.state && <pre>
                {JSON.stringify(location.state, null, 2)}
            </pre>} */}
            <Link to={`/users/${Number(id) + 1}`}>Next User</Link>
        </div >
    )
}

export default UserDetail
```

I tried giving the id as a hook but when I click on the next user button the page does not refresh automatically. When I refresh the browser, useEffect is working.

```
const { id } = useParams();
  ...

useEffect(() => {()=>
{
      // FETCH
}, [id]);
```

Comment: How do you know the effect isnt running? Is it by observing there was not a fetch, or putting loggin ABOVE that if condition in there? (latter is what you should check)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you switch from one user to another, the component won't remount so:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(location.state);
```

Is stuck on the previous `location.state` value. Therefore it may be stuck on one which does not pass the condition `!user?.id`.

I suspect this will be the case because `location.state` is the push state, and that means if you visit this page from the outside, or if you click on a `<Link>` like yours which does not redefine the push state, it will empty. But I think using this in the first place was an accident. Please note the `location.state` property is not related to the params. It's an entirely different mechanism that looks irrelevant here.

So the `if` condition does not pass and the `fetch` never happens.

The use of `location.state` as a default value does not make sense. I think this should just be `null` or `undefined`.

And then make the condition in the effect actually check the param and not the user you already have (might not even have it yet), or when you fetch the first user, it will never evaluate to true inside that if condition ever again since `user.id` is populated.

It also doesn't make sense for `user` to be in the effect deps. That would create an infinite loop with these other changes (I think maybe that's when you added conditions that didn't make sense). You only care about if the URL ID changes in that effect and that's it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link, useParams, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function UserDetail() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const location = useLocation();
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    console.log(location)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (id !== undefined) {
            fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => setUser(data))
            console.log("if olan")
        }

    }, [id])


    return (
        <div>
            <h2>
                User Detail
            </h2>

            {user && <pre>
                {JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}
            </pre>}
            <Link to={`/users/${Number(id) + 1}`}>Next User</Link>
        </div >
    )
}

export default UserDetail
```

Comment: The !user?.id statement is to prevent fetch from working if there is a value carried by state. This expression works fine when opening details from the user list or going directly to the url (in case there is no state). The only thing I don't understand is why useEffect doesn't work even though the id change is detected by console.log. (When I run the code you specified above, it goes into an infinite loop)

Comment: As above, please try this code, your problem will go away. Your state management is confused and mixing multiple concepts in the `user` state. Your effect will be running on the old code, its the if guard inside thats returning false so it looks like nothing is happening. You don't want to prevent fetch if theres a value in state. *That state of the first user you visited still will still be there even when you click the link*. The component rerenders when you click it, it does not "reset".

Comment: Oh I fixed an infinite loop problem, please check again. have edited

Comment: It also explains why it works when you opening from another page, or going to the URL. In this case, the state is destroyed since the component unmounted. In the case of the "Next User" link, the component it directs to is already mounted, only the ID changes. That means it just rerenders and keeps the old state around.